# Azurite always returns status Forbidden

Tags: c#, azure, queue

I'm trying to send a message to an Azure Storage Queue rast API using the following C# code, but it always returns a "Forbidden" status code. Can someone help me identify the issue? I have read that it could be the system date time, but as far that i can see this is correct. ChatGPT gave some suggestions, but i still cant figure it out.

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public async Task PostOrderAsync(Order order)
    {
        string storageAccountName = "devstoreaccount1";
        string storageAccountKey = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==";
        string queueName = "test";
        string baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:10001";
        string message = "Hello, Azurite Queue!";

        // Create a Shared Key Signature for authentication
        string sharedKey = GenerateSharedKey(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey, queueName);
        Console.WriteLine(sharedKey);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Create the HTTP request to add a message to the queue
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}/{storageAccountName}/{queueName}/messages?visibilitytimeout=600&messagettl=600");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-12-12");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R"));
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R"));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", sharedKey);
            request.Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message added to the queue.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to add the message to the queue. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static string GenerateSharedKey(string accountName, string accountKey, string queueName)
    {
        // Create a string to sign
        string stringToSign = $"POST\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

        // Append the canonicalized headers
        stringToSign += "x-ms-date:" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\n";
        stringToSign += "x-ms-version:2019-12-12" + "\n";

        // Append the canonicalized resource
        stringToSign += $"/{accountName}/{queueName}/messages";

        // Create an HMAC-SHA256 signature using the account key
        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey);
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            byte[] signature = hmac.ComputeHash(data);
            string base64Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            return $"SharedKey {accountName}:{base64Signature}";
        }
    }
}
```

The sharedkey that is generated looks like this

> SharedKey devstoreaccount1:g0W5gdS3Au5BrdMQ56PxwQAVLjyy8V9BGAWo/piToqA=

I dont know if the time convertion is working good. The request time is

> Sat, 14 Oct 2023 11:05:31 GMT

And the azurite service inside rider logs this

> 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2023:11:05:31 +0000] "POST /devstoreaccount1/test/messages HTTP/1.1" 403 -